# How do I make pytest fixtures work with decorated functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator, pytest

py.test seems to fail when I decorate test functions which has a fixture as an argument.

```
def deco(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@pytest.fixture
def x():
    return 0

@deco
def test_something(x):
    assert x == 0
```

In this simple example, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: test_something() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given).
```

Is there a way to fix this, preferably without modifying the decorator too much? (Since the decorator is used outside testing code too.)

Comment: interestingly... seems to work ok for me with just `functools.wraps` in Python 3.6.  Fails in 2.7

Comment: This question doesnt have sense  in current python versions

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks like functools.wraps does not do the job well enough, so it breaks py.test's introspection.

Creating the decorator using the [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) package seems to do the trick.

```
import decorator

def deco(func):
    def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator.decorator(wrapper, func)
```

Comment: It could be useful to know that pytest depends on decorator, so you don't need to pull in any new dependency.

Comment: How shall we handle passing an argument to deco when using this e.g. @deco(3)

Comment: why are there two uses of `func` in your answer? is that intentional?

Comment: @joel it seems intentional. Without second `func` decorator doesn't work, though even PyCharm warns about shadowing name from outer scope.

Comment: @zneak Do you recall your env? Because `import decorator` does not work for me without a separate package install on pytest 7.2 (2022) Mac or pytest 2.8.7 (2016) Linux. And pip3 does not list `decorator` as among the requirements for either one.

Comment: @Noah this question is about a decade old. Today, I'd recommend [wrapt](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt/) over decorator.

Comment: @jck Ha, well, appreciate your responding after all this time. (Can't install anything new in the product I'm working on, but `functools.wraps` ended up working for me.)

Answer (score 7):

Fixture feature depends on test function signature.

If you can change wrapper signature as follow, it will works.

```
def deco(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(x):
        return func(x)
    return wrapper
```

If you can't change it, make another decorator:

```
def deco(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def deco_x(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(x):
        return func(x)
    return wrapper
```

And decorate `test_somthing` with `deco_x`:

```
@deco_x
@deco
def test_something(x):
    assert x == 0
```

Comment: @KjeldFlarup, How about [jck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614807/2225682) ?

Comment: What to do if I want to pass an argument to decorator itself. e.g. @deco_x(2)

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are using a pytest fixture with a decorator while passing data to the decorator, you can do it as follows:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def data(request):
    data = list(range(10))
    yield data

def decorator_with_variable_and_fixture(whatever):
    def wrap(test_func):
        def wrapper(data):
            mod = whatever.lower()[::-1]
            test_func(data, mod)
        return wrapper
    return wrap

@decorator_with_variable_and_fixture(whatever='SOMETHING!')
def test_decorator_with_variable_and_fixture(data, whatever):
    for i in data:
        print(whatever[i]*(i+1))
    assert whatever == '!gnihtemos'
    assert data == list(range(10))
```

Note how `data` is passed to the `wrapper` function - this way pytest's fixture approach still works correctly.

This is quite handy for example if you need to pass a PySpark session around, while using a decorator to perform other functionality.