# python decorator takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given after modifying for pytest

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I'd appreciate some help with the following code, as I'm still relatively new to Python, and despite countless days trying to figure out where i'm going wrong, i cant seem to spot the error i'm making.

I've adapted the following code from an article on medium to create a logging decorator and then enhanced it to try and "redact pandas df and dictionary" from the logs. Using functools caused me a problem with pytest and pytest fixtures. A post on stack overflow suggested dropping functools in favour of decorators.

```
def log_decorator(_func=None):
    def log_decorator_info(func):
        def log_decorator_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
            _logger = Logger()
            logger_obj = _logger.get_logger()

            args_passed_in_function = args_excl_df_dict(*args)
            kwargs_passed_in_function = kwargs_excl_df_dict(**kwargs)
           formatted_arguments = join_args_kwargs(args_passed_in_function,kwargs_passed_in_function)
        
            py_file_caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
            extra_args = { 'func_name_override': func.__name__,'file_name_override': os.path.basename(py_file_caller.filename) }

            """ Before to the function execution, log function details."""
            logger_obj.info(f"Begin function - Arguments: {formatted_arguments}", extra=extra_args)
        
            try:
                """ log return value from the function """
            
                args_returned_from_function = args_excl_df_dict(func(*args))
                kwargs_returned_from_function = []
                formatted_arguments = join_args_kwargs(args_returned_from_function,kwargs_returned_from_function)
            
                logger_obj.info(f"End function - Returned: {formatted_arguments}", extra=extra_args)
       
            except:
                """log exception if occurs in function"""
                error_raised = str(sys.exc_info()[1])
            
                logger_obj.error(f"Exception: {str(sys.exc_info()[1])}",extra=extra_args)
            
                msg_to_send = f"{func.__name__} {error_raised}"
               send_alert(APP_NAME,msg_to_send,'error')
            
               raise
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorator.decorator(log_decorator_wrapper, func)
    if _func is None:
        return log_decorator_info
    else:
        return log_decorator_info(_func)
```

Having adapted the above code i cant figure out what is causing the following error

> args_returned_from_function = args_excl_df_dict(func(*args))
> TypeError: test_me() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Other functions which the log decorator relies on

```
def args_excl_df_dict(*args):
    args_list = []
    for a in args:
        if isinstance(a,(pd.DataFrame,dict)):
            a = 'redacted from log'
            args_list.append(repr(a))
        else: 
            args_list.append(repr(a))
    return args_list

def kwargs_excl_df_dict(**kwargs):
    kwargs_list = []
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(v,(dict,pd.DataFrame)):
            v = 'redacted from log'
            kwargs_list.append(f"{k}={v!r}")
        else:
            kwargs_list.append(f"{k}={v!r}")
    return kwargs_list

def join_args_kwargs(args,kwargs):

    formatted_arguments = ", ".join(args + kwargs)
    return str(formatted_arguments)
```

This is the code calling the decorator

```
@log_decorator.log_decorator()
def test_me(a, b, c, d):
    return a, b

test_me(string, number, dictionary, pandas_df)
```

Comment: Why is the decorator `@log_decorator.log_decorator()` and not just `@log_decorator` ?  is the first part a class name or module name or namespace?

Comment: Its a module name - log_decorator.py

Comment: and what about `decorator.decorator` in the return statement?  Where does that come from?

Comment: This is a module thats imported from PyPI - "import decorator". I could see part of the problem i was having using functools and pytest fixtures, was pytest fixtures werent being retained by the decorator - similar to the issue mentioned on this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614658/how-do-i-make-pytest-fixtures-work-with-decorated-functions. I therefore tried to follow this example of using decorator to see if that would resolve the problem but got the above instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the wrapper is including the function as an argument to the function.

Try adding this line and see if it helps

```
args = args[1:]
```

intor your log_decorator_wrapper function towards the top.  Like this.

```
def log_decorator(_func=None):
    def log_decorator_info(func):
        def log_decorator_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            args = args[1:]   # < -------------------here
            _logger = Logger()
            logger_obj = _logger.get_logger()

            args_passed_in_function = args_excl_df_dict(*args)
            kwargs_passed_in_function = kwargs_excl_df_dict(**kwargs)
           formatted_arguments = join_args_kwargs(args_passed_in_function,kwargs_passed_in_function)
        
            py_file_caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
            extra_args = { 'func_name_override': func.__name__,'file_name_override': os.path.basename(py_file_caller.filename) }

            """ Before to the function execution, log function details."""
            logger_obj.info(f"Begin function - Arguments: {formatted_arguments}", extra=extra_args)
        
            try:
                """ log return value from the function """
            
                args_returned_from_function = args_excl_df_dict(func(*args))
                kwargs_returned_from_function = []
                formatted_arguments = join_args_kwargs(args_returned_from_function,kwargs_returned_from_function)
            
                logger_obj.info(f"End function - Returned: {formatted_arguments}", extra=extra_args)
       
            except:
                """log exception if occurs in function"""
                error_raised = str(sys.exc_info()[1])
            
                logger_obj.error(f"Exception: {str(sys.exc_info()[1])}",extra=extra_args)
            
                msg_to_send = f"{func.__name__} {error_raised}"
               send_alert(APP_NAME,msg_to_send,'error')
            
               raise
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorator.decorator(log_decorator_wrapper, func)
    if _func is None:
        return log_decorator_info
    else:
        return log_decorator_info(_func)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, looks like it solved the problem. Thanks again @alexpdev

Answer (score -1):

If your code is as is in your editor, maybe look at the indentation on the first three functions. Then start from there to move down

Comment: This was just copy paste error into stack and its properly indented on VSC